# How can I solve a boundary value numerically on an infinite interval?

Tags: differential-equations

Consider the differential equation $ -y''(x)+x^{4}y(x)-E_{n}y(x)=0 $ with the boundary conditions $ y(0)=0=y(\infty).$

How can I use the shooting method or other numerical methods to solve this equation? My only idea is to set $ R=10000 $ for example and solve $ y(0)=0=y(R) $,

Of course I also could make the substitution $u= \frac{x}{x-1}$ so the new boundary conditions could become $ y(0)=0=y(1) $ but now the differential equation becomes singular at the point $ u=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're facing a singular Sturm-Liouville eigenvalue problem. One way you may be able to use the shooting method is to get an asymptotic expansion of your solution at the $x=\infty$ (Frobenius or WKB methods should work). Using the asymptotics to evaluate $y(x)$ and $y'(x)$ at some finite $x$ and then shoot from there to $x=0$ to find the eigenvalue.

On the other hand, there exists a fairly well developed numerical library, based also on a sound mathematical analysis of the Sturm-Liouville problem, that is already available. It should be able to handle your problem directly. Look up the [SLEIGN2](http://www.math.niu.edu/SL2/) package and its documentation.

Answer (score 2):

See the recent preprints of Andre Voros on the arXiv. He proposed an iterative algorithm, and
Artur Avila recently proved convergence. The literature on this problem is enormous;
it usually goes under the title "anharmonic oscillator" or "quartic oscillator".
The rate of convergence of Voros algorithm is geometric.